# Trying to tag parts of a word and keep track of any changes that happen to those parts

Tags: algorithms, strings, natural-language-processing, computational-linguistics

I'm a researcher working with a language that has gone through phonological changes through time.  I would like to tag parts of a word (i.e. prefix, stem, suffix) and then apply those phonological changes and then see what is left or different about the stuff that I tagged.

I'm currently using Python with some regex stuff to apply the changes so if I can do this using its NPL toolkit that would be perfect.  I've start to mess around with it but I haven't found anything that will work just yet.  I'm also not sure if this toolkit would be the best for this.

For example, I apply the following transformation to tag `re`, `peat` and `ed` in `repeated`:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathtt{repeated}
  & \xrightarrow{\mathtt{rep} \mapsto \mathtt{rp}} \mathtt{rpeated} \\
  & \xrightarrow{\mathtt{ea} \mapsto \mathtt{e}} \mathtt{rpeted} \\
  & \xrightarrow{\mathtt{d}\$ \mapsto \epsilon} \mathtt{rpete} \\
\end{align}
$$

I would like to be able to find out what is left of the stuff I tagged.  So I'd like to see that `r` is all that is left of the prefix, `pe` is all that is left of the stem, etc.  Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sequence alignments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) with a suitable score. You then get something like this:

$\qquad\displaystyle
\begin{array}{cccccc}
  r & e & p & e & a & t & e & d \\
  r & - & p & e & - & t & e & -
\end{array}$

Now, if you have marked the original word, you can read off that -- according to your alignment score -- only "r" is left from the prefix, "pet" from the stem and "e" from the suffix.

The score makes a difference when parts may be assigned to e.g. prefix or stem. [Levenstein/edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_distance) and [Damerau-Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) may be good starting points. Play around with the penalties a bit; note that you can assign costs depending on whether you match against prefix, stem or suffix (if you have marked the original words) and use things like [affine gap costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_penalty#Affine).